# AppSetting Transformation failing to read ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment

Tags: asp.net, environment-variables, startup, appsettings

When I change my ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to "staging" or anything else on my local machine the application is seeing the environment name as "Development".

**My Environment variable is currently set up like this:**

[image]

**And my Startup class constructor is:**

```
public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
        Env = env;
    }
```

But When I run the application and hover over env.EnvironmentName I see "Development".
When I run this on the staging server which also has its ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT set to "Staging" it's transformed to "Production".

It's as if the application isn't looking for the variable at all.

I've been staring at this for a while and using my favorite search engine to find an answer but I'm a little stumped. I know I have done this before without issue.

Advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Small update. I'd not considered the contents of the launchsettings.json file which is why the app wasn't picking up the environment variable locally running in IIS Express.
However, the app still fails to use the environment variable on the Staging server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I "fixed" it.

I was personally unaware that when adding an environment variable the machine on which it's being added must be restarted. After restarting the staging server, the environment is being correctly picked up.

Hopefully someone arriving via Google search might find this useful one day.